# SVG not correctly sizing to size of container in a flexbox in Firefox and Edge

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to have an svg with a specific aspect ratio viewBox resize inside a flex item that takes up the 'remainder' of its parent.

The intention is for the SVG to always have the correct aspect ratio and have space along the sides to keep the ratio intact as the page size changes. This works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox and Edge the svg seems to resize to fit the maximum width of its container and keeps the aspect ratio by resizing its height and the height of the container. I need it to resize itself to the container size and never 'spill out' of the container.

Does anyone have any idea what I can do to make it work in all three browsers? Here's the code:

```css
.parent {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

.header-child {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: black;
}

.svg-child {
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="header-child"></div>
  <div class="svg-child">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet" height="100%" width="100%">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="blue" />
            <rect x="90" y="190" width="10" height="10" fill="yellow" />
           </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want them to all size like chrome (the central image):

[image]

This is a minimal reproduction of a problem in a much larger system. The parent div, in the actual product, is hosted inside another div that is itself a flex item. Pasting the above code into a text document and opening it in all 3 browsers will reproduce the actual issue I am having though.

The problem, at its heart, is that when the Firefox browser is resized the size of the container div is resized to fit the svg instead of the svg resizing (with correct aspect ratio for the viewbox) to fit the container div.

I don't really care about making it work in Edge, but Firefox is a must.

Comment: are you using  `html,body{height:100%}` ?

Comment: I am in the actual solution Tenami. This is part of a larger page layout and resides in a flex item of its own, but the page has a 100% height on html and body.

Comment: so add it to the code so it reflect your real use case

Comment: This is a minimal reproduce. The html at 100% in this case isn't overly important as this is a small part of a much larger system. Cutting a pasting the given code into a text document and opening it in all the browsers will reproduce the issue I'm seeing in the actual product.

Comment: your code doens't reproduce the behavior your are describing and when you say: *he parent div, in the actual product, is hosted inside another div that is itself a flex item.* --> this is the important part but you omit it in the code

Comment: It's not the important part. If I copy that code into a text document, save it as .html and load it into all three browsers on both linux and windows it reproduces the problem I am having. The issue seems to be that in Firefox (and Edge) the SVG is resized to fill the width and then the height is resized to keep the aspect ratio. I want the width to resize due to the container the svg sits in not having enough height to display the entire svg if the width is at 100%

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways to solve your problem.

**1st way**, use `html, body { height: 100% }` and apply `min-height: 0` to both `.parent` and `.svg-child`:

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 0;
}

.header-child {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: black;
}

.svg-child {
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="header-child"></div>
  <div class="svg-child">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet" height="100%" width="100%">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="blue" />
      <rect x="90" y="190" width="10" height="10" fill="yellow" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

**2nd way**, use `vh` for `parent` height (`.parent { height: 100vh; }`) and set `.svg-child { min-height: 0; }`:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header-child {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: black;
}

.svg-child {
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="header-child"></div>
  <div class="svg-child">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet" height="100%" width="100%">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red"/>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="blue"/>
      <rect x="90" y="190" width="10" height="10" fill="yellow"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Live page demo working on **Chrome**, **Firefox** and **Edge**: https://zikro.gr/dbg/so/59679937/

Answer (score 1):

> Solution 1 using view-port units

These units `vh` `vw` allow you to specify sizes in terms of percentages of the view-port `width` and view-port `height`.

[Read more about vh and vw](https://www.quirksmode.org/css/units-values/viewport.html)

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.parent {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

.header-child {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: black;
}

.svg-child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.svg-child svg{

  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="header-child"></div>
  <div class="svg-child">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet" height="100%" width="100%">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="blue" />
            <rect x="90" y="190" width="10" height="10" fill="yellow" />
           </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Solution 2 using Height `media-quires` units

```
@media screen and (max-width: 995px) , screen and (max-height: 700px) {
  .svg-child svg{
      height: 100vh;
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/height)

Or you can only use height media query alone

```
@media (min-height: 800px) {
 .svg-child svg{
     height: 90vh;
   }
}
```

***You can change the setting accordingly***